# How to insert scroll bar in WPF in code behind for RadMenu

Tags: wpf, scrollbar, radmenu

[image]

This Radmenu is dynamically created in code behind.Please let me know how to add scroll bar in this menu to limit the items in the submenu.

Comment: [telerik forum](http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/wpf/context-menu.aspx) seems like the place to ask that question

Comment: ok thnx...I have searched in it..

Comment: Try explicitly setting the Height property of the Menu for that has a lot of menu items and that should add (Up/Down) button I believe

Comment: K T - why have you accepted only 4 answers for you 16 questions? And why do you ignore any comments?

Answer (score 0):

Check out [this post](http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/wpf/context-menu/scrollbar-on-a-radcontextmenu.aspx) from telerik forums.
Though it's in silverlight, I'm pretty sure you can use it as is.

Answer (score 0):

Try explicitly setting the Height property of the Menu for that has a lot of menu items and that should add (Up/Down) button I believe

Answer (score 0):

While not a scrollbar, you can set the DropDownHeight property of the RadMenuItem.  It limits the height taken by the child menu items, and has up/down arrows to enable the scrolling.